# best way to find indices and change value in python

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity

I have a numpy.ndarray X. I want to find all the places in X that X>threshold, and then do X=threshold.

What is the cheapest way (in terms of time-complexity) to do this? I need to run this procedure millions of times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use the numpy indexing in order to replace all elements that bigger than some threshold.

Although, I'm not sure it's the fastest way.

```
threshold = 10 # for example
some_array[some_array > threshold] = threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

try numpy.where:

```
    from numpy import where

    Y  = where( X> treshold, threshold,X)
```

where applies and if statement in the ufunc-manner with **where( condition, if True, else )**